# Integrating along a line of point sources

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, functions

I have some concentration that radiates from a spherical point, being steadily consumed until it hits zero at some distance $r_{n}$. This is  given by

$$C(r) = A\left[r^2 + \frac{2r_{n}^3}{r} - 3r_{n}^2\right]$$

where $A$ is a constant. Now, Imagine I have an infinite line of such emitters along the vertical axis. at some distance $r$ I would like to know the total concentration at a perpendicular distance $r$ from that "line source". It's tempting to think that the solution is simply

$$2 \int_{r_{n}}^r C(r) dr$$

to factor in contributions above and below. But this can't be the true solution as it stands as it would produce units of concentration $\times$ distance rather than just concentration; I've tried several approaches but I am not satisfied with the logical rigour of any of the attempts I've made. Is there something fundamentally wrong about summing all the contributions this way, or some major logical step I'm missing, and if there some reason why this cannot work?

Any advice is welcome!

[image: sketch of situation]